# Problems with rails 4 in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I create a new rails 4beta1 app (ruby 2.0) from scratch and when I launch de server in development mode it runs fine but when I try in production it doesn't.

I already try to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and change the `config.serve_static_assets` to true in the `config/environments/production` file but I still got the error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0.beta1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-04-03 11:53:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-03 11:53:46] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
[2013-04-03 11:53:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13848 port=3000
I, [2013-04-03T11:53:50.521162 #13848]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-03 11:53:50 +0100
F, [2013-04-03T11:53:50.695426 #13848] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/jbatista/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/jbatista/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/jbatista/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Webpage error:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 4.0, for technical reasons the default Rails page doesn't work on production environment, this includes any server (like heroku). The good news is that the error will go away when you start add controllers, set routes, etc...

Just start development and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

also looks like you need to define the root route in `config/routes.rb`
something like

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "MyApp#index"
end
```

where `MyApp` refers to your applications name.

Comment: Nop, the problems wasn't about that. It's a technical change in rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environments/production.rb` serve_static_assets should be false because in production their server will handle them.

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Moreover, you **should not** use WEBrick in production, it should only be used in development. Go for [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) for example instead.

[image]

Basically, add `gem 'thin'` to our Gemfile.